# Transmit BLOB data from server (DB) to wpf client via WCF data services?

Tags: wpf, wcf-data-services

I am developing a wpf client application to allow a remote client to access media resource saved as BLOB in sql server DB.I researched and found wcf data service stream provider  can be used to acheive this.Is there any other efficient(performance wise) way to do this.Also suggest some help with my current approach.help will be really appreciated.